# the system does not see the wifi equipment

Tags: wireless, settings

Good afternoon. Installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on a mini PC Z83-V But the system does not see the wifi equipment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -nnk -d ::0280` command